# Php fastest way to get property names from inherited object

Tags: php, reflection, properties

Im having one generic class which all my entity classes extends from. 
I use this class to put everything that is generic. For example get properties.
Which is the fastest way to do this and at the same time be able to have 
private properties in the extended class.

```
class myObj{
private strInternal;


public function getPropertyNames(){

/* Here I want function which returns all properties of the CHILD
* array_keys (get_class_vars( get_class($this) ) returns also strInternal
* which I don't want. Is ReflectionClass best alternative?
*/
}
}

class randomObj extends myObj {
protected property1;
protected property2;
protected property3;
}


test = new randomObj();
print_r ( test->getPropertyNames());
```

Comment: I will use  I will use ReflectionClass::getProperties. Case solved

Comment: you can also check `get_object_vars()`